# How to run a command while logging output to a file?

Tags: io-redirection, stderr

I have a console application that needs to be run as part of the deployment of a new application version on my server.

This console application is designed to output to the console, and cannot be changed.

I'd like to run it as normal, but have stdout and stderr logged to a file at the same time they're output to the console.

How can I do that on Linux?

Comment: Search for [`tee`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=tee), plenty of answers.

Comment: another way would be to do:   `script -a the_logfile`  #and then run the apps from the 'script' environment, which will log also special characters, ctrl codes, etc, and could be used to "replay" the display if you manage to use it properly, ie watching the log from the same type of terminal and usnig the same lines/columns, and using a "more" or "less" that outputs control chars (ex: `more -v the_logfile`)

Comment: Is this an application that prints a stream of text, or a full-screen text-mode application?

Comment: @Gilles Just a stream of text!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tee`.  For example:

```
ls -l / | tee tmp.txt
```

Will print to stdout, and `tmp.txt` will contain a copy of the output.  If you want to include stderr in tmp.txt:

```
ls -l / 2>&1 | tee tmp.txt
```

Comment: Great thanks, just tried it but it looks like it's logging only stdout, is it possible to log stderr as well?

Comment: @Benjamin That should be `cmd 2>&1 | tee ...`.  I edited this in.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `tee` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

To pipe only stdout

```
cmd | tee log.txt | less
```

To pipe both stdout and stderr:

```
cmd >>(tee stdout.log) 2>>(tee stderr.log >&2)
```

Comment: Should the `> >` be `>>`?

Comment: Thanks. Will prefer @goldilocks's answer though because I want both stdout and stderr in the same file, just like I would see them on the console!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this.

1. `nohup 2>&1 application &`. This will send all output to a file called nohup.out. It will also capture SIGHUPs. So you can close the shell and it will keep running. If you wish tyo see what is happening then you can follow the output with `tail -f nohop.out`.
2. The [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command will do the same without preventing SIGHUP. C2h and goldilock already mention this.
3. If you only need limited scrollback, try [`screen -L`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). This is explained in more detail [in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/237988/is-there-a-way-to-save-whats-printed-on-the-display-with-gnu-screen).

I realise that screen is a workaround way, but its other features are very nice for deployements.